# Blender Render, can't render a background

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am new to blender, and I just finished my first low poly scene. I would like to add a night sky background, but when I click render, the sky disappears.

Is there a way to render my scene with the background? I have the Sky option checked in the 'Shading' tab as well as in the Render Layer.

Comment: Please clarify.  "I click" please elaborate.  Are you using Blender Render or Cycles render?

Answer (score 3):

- Assuming Blender Render
- Blender has background which can appear in the render.  With the camera selected and shading panel verify that alpha has sky selected.
- Under the layers tab you must have Sky selected as well

[image]