# sky background not rendering with scene

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render a scene and when I render it, my background doesn't show up. It should be a sky that is blue, but it shows up black still while the hills and other features render fine. Does anyone know a reason this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31050/blender-render-cant-render-a-background, sky enabled?

Comment: Can you send an image or the blend file so we can take a look I to it